# SQL SUM OVER query doesn't return a sum

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a bunch of solar generation data I want to analyse and show in a graph. In this case, I want to show the Sum and Average of each month in each year from my DB (MariaDB) (perhaps also with an error bar showing a single standard deviation for the values in each month - though this is secondary)

The relevant table is DTP:

```
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idDTP | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| DT    | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| PWR   | varchar(6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My query is:

```
SELECT YEAR(DT) AS 'Year',
       MONTH(DT) AS 'Month',  
       SUM(PWR) OVER(PARTITION BY Month,Year) AS 'Total Monthly Power (kWh)', 

FROM DTP GROUP BY YEAR(DT), MONTH(DT);
```

When I run this on the MariaDB Console, I get this result:

```
+------+-------+-------------------------+
| Year | Month | Total Monthly Power kWh |
+------+-------+-------------------------+
| 2012 |     2 |                    0.03 |
| 2012 |     3 |                   0.012 |
| 2012 |     4 |                   0.012 |
| 2012 |     5 |                   0.006 |
| 2012 |     6 |                   0.036 |
| 2012 |     7 |                   0.006 |
| 2012 |     8 |                   0.006 |
| 2012 |     9 |                   0.018 |
| 2012 |    10 |                   0.012 |
| 2012 |    11 |                   0.012 |
| 2012 |    12 |                   0.018 |
| 2013 |     1 |                   0.012 |
| 2013 |     2 |                   0.024 |
| 2013 |     3 |                   0.024 |
| 2013 |     4 |                    0.03 |
| 2013 |     5 |                    0.03 |
| 2013 |     6 |                   0.006 |
| 2013 |     7 |                   0.024 |
| 2013 |     8 |                   0.024 |
| 2013 |     9 |                   0.018 |
| 2013 |    10 |                   0.048 |
| 2013 |    11 |                   0.012 |
| 2013 |    12 |                   0.036 |
| 2014 |     1 |                   0.012 |
| 2014 |     2 |                   0.018 |
| 2014 |     3 |                   0.024 |
| 2014 |     4 |                   0.006 |
| 2014 |     5 |                   0.006 |
| 2014 |     6 |                   0.024 |
| 2014 |     7 |                   0.012 |
| 2014 |     8 |                   0.018 |
| 2014 |     9 |                   0.006 |
```

etc...

It's clearly not summing all the records in the PWR column for each month, in each year. Any thoughts on a working Query.

Comment: Why is your field PWR in string datatype instead of float/number?

Comment: If you are using a group by, don't need that window function. Also, if PWR is going to use floats, why do you define it as Varchar?. Using proper data types is a good practice

Comment: Bad design: PWR should be `decimal`, idDTP should be int `unsigned`, since auto_increment generated numbers are always positive numbers.

Comment: @FriendlyDragon, Nacho and Georg Richter It's a varchar because it's from my solar panels as a string value. I use Python to import hundreds of these files into the DB and I decided that because SQL dynamically casts values as required, the design isn't bad, unless it's the reason why I'm not seeing the SUM working. If MySQL _IS_ capable of casting the value to FLOAT, then you're answering the wrong question. I want to know how to get the SUM working. Nacho, for your answer to be useful, you'll need to explain what you mean by the window function, perhaps with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That your query even runs shows a lot of weaknesses on MariaDB's side. Your query is invalid for several reasons:

1. `AS 'Year'`: Year is not a string literal. Aliases need double quotes instead. (MariaDb also allows backticks depanding on the mode it runs in.)
2. `PWR` is is string. You cannot get a add up strings.
3. `SUM(PWR) OVER(...)`. There is no PWR in your intermediate result, so you cannot add it up.

So, what does MariaDB do here?

1. MariaDB let's the wrong delimiters for your alias slip.
2. This is a heritage of MySQL. The two DBMS convert any string into numbers without ever raising an error. '100' becomes 100, '2k' becomes 2 and 'my brain hurts' becomes 0. Why is that? The DBMS just takes as many places from the left as it is numeric (e.g. the 2 in '2k'). When there is no number at all, the conversion defaults to 0.
3. The `SUM OVER`  should not work in any circumstance. For this to understand we will have to imagine the same query with a select clause for the year, month and PWR, because we need these three columns, to run over the result to get the sum of the PWR's per year and month. But if we replace the `SUM OVER` line with just the PWR, then the DBMS will raise the error `DTP.PWR' isn't in GROUP BY`. (Provided you don't have cheat mode enabled, where MariaDB allows invalid `GROUP BY` queries. Make sure there is always 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' set.) You can see that you cannot put PWR in the select clause, because the DBMS would not know which row's PWR to pick per year and month, as there is no aggregation function invoked on it (like `MIN(pwr)` or `MAX(pwr)`). Somehow though, MariaDB conjures a value here, obviously by picking one arbitrarily from the group's rows.

Your query corrected (assuming that you want to select the `SUM(pwr)` per month:

```
SELECT YEAR(DT) AS "Year",
       MONTH(DT) AS "Month",
       SUM(PWR) AS "Total Monthly Power (kWh)"
FROM DTP
GROUP BY YEAR(DT), MONTH(DT)
ORDER BY YEAR(DT), MONTH(DT);
```

This works, but you should correct your data model and change the PWR column to a numeric type, of course.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/IJLPyqUb

Comment: Thanks Stu. The OVER was there because as well as summing per month/year, I was also trying to generate a standard deviation value for each month to show the variability through each month. OVER seemed a way to scope the STDEV() function to a month

Comment: Well, `STDDEV(PWR)` would give you the standard deviation of a month over its days. `STDDEV(SUM(PWR)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(DT))` would give you the standard deviation of a month's total in relation to the other months in the year. And `STDDEV(SUM(PWR)) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(DT))` would give you the standard deviation of a month's total in relation to the same month in other years. Is one of these what you are looking for?

Comment: All of those look useful. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

CAST(PWR AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) it’s too short. It doesn’t need to be varchar(6)